# AGGREGAT with critiera and duplicates in array

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
      A            B               C               D              E
1   ProdID       Price       Unique ProdID     1. Biggest     2. Biggest
2   2606639       40            2606639           50            50         
3   2606639       50            4633523           45            35
4   2606639       20            3911436           25            25
5   2606639       50
6   4633523       45
7   4633523       20
8   4633523       35
9   3911436       20
10  3911436       25
11  3911436       25
12  3911436       15
```

In **Cells D2:E4** I want to show the *1. biggest and 2. biggest* price of each ProdID in **Column A**. Therefore, I use the following formula:

```
D2 =AGGREGAT(14,6,$B$2:$B$12/($A$2:$A$12=$C2),1)
E2 =AGGREGAT(14,6,$B$2:$B$12/($A$2:$A$12=$C2),2)
```

This formula works as long as the prices are unique in **Column B** as you can see on the second ProdID (4633523).

However, once the price is not unique in **Column B** *(for example 50 for ProdID 26026639 and 25 for ProdID 3911436)* the functions in Cells D2:E4 does not show the right results.

Do you have an idea if you can solve this issue with the AGGREGAT-Formula and wihtout using an ARRAY-Formula?

Answer (score 0):

you could check number of occurences of the first ProdID-price combinations and use that in the last argument of the AGGREGAT function. So instead of

```
=AGGREGAT(14,6,$B$2:$B$12/($A$2:$A$12=$C2),2)
```

you would have

```
=AGGREGAT(14,6,$B$2:$B$12/($A$2:$A$12=$C2),2+COUNTIFS(A:A,C2,B:B,D2)-1)
```

of course you can just put "1+COUNTIFS..." but I put it this way so it can be better understood that it uses position 2 + number of occurences of the combination of ProdID with biggest number after the first occurence.

Comment: Hi Pavel, nice idea but as far as I could see this solution only works if the values in Column A exist exactly two times. However, it could also happen that the values exist more than 2 times. For example for ProdID 2606639 it might happen that the price of 50 applies to all 3 of the ProdIDs instead of only 2. The list in the end will change on a frequent basis so there is no guarantee that it remains with the same values as in my posted example.

Comment: not exactly two times. You can put as many lines of the same ProdID as you want and it will give you second higherst unique price. But yes, in case there is only one unique price for the given ProdID then it will result in error, which is in essence correct, because there is no second biggest number. But it can be that I misunderstand - if there is only one unique price for the ID what would you like it to do?